# How to get stdout of a "lost" session

Tags: linux, shell, ps, stdout

I don't well what's the name of the situation, I think yesterday I closed a session with a background ipython process, but I am still able to connect to it (the process is running a web server and I can load the page). Can I still get to see the stdout/stderr of the process?

If I run `ps -f -Umyname` I get (I deleted some unrelated lines, but the PID and PPID are the real ones):

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
16131     1767  1765  0 11:20 ?        S      0:03 sshd: myname@notty
16131     1946 21019  0 11:25 ?        Sl     1:47 /usr/bin/python -m IPython.kernel -f /home/myname/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-c72091
16131     3946 21019  0 14:37 pts/3    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
16131     4003  4001  0 14:38 ?        S      0:01 sshd: myname@pts/14
16131     4004  4003  0 14:38 pts/14   Ss     0:00 -bash
16131     6366  4004  0 16:41 pts/14   R+     0:00 ps -f Umyname
16131    21019     1  0 Jul30 ?        Sl     0:52 /usr/bin/python ipython notebook
```

I am sure it's not being ran inside a screen. Any idea? I am interest in PID 21019

Comment: Would like to discover best techical name for this situation, too :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `strace` to see the output of a running process.

```bsh
$ strace -p 21019 -e write=1,2
```

The above command will attach to the process with PID 21019 and trace write-calls to fd 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr).

When you're done, you can send a `sigint` (to strace) to detach (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>).

*edit:
There are also some tools that allow you to attach a running process to a new terminal, e.g. [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), screenify, retty. Note that most of these use strace, gdb or similar trace-tools to accomplish this, but they tend to produce prettier output.*

Comment: I got 
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

Unfortunately I have not root access in this system, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: strace can not run in docker https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20064, To turn off security features use:
`docker run --security-opt seccomp:unconfined ...`

Comment: I had the same sudo issue. Did it afterwards with sudo, and it's hanging on `restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>`

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell strace to only output ASCII line by line, as if I had started the process in a terminal? Right now I see both ASCII and hex but the ASCII is all garbled / split up over multiple lines.